# "NTLDR is missing. Press Ctrl+Alt+Del to restart." how to troubleshoot.?

Tags: windows-xp

I removed my Laptop hard disk and put in a casing thereby making it an external hard disk.

Later I formatted the C: partition by connecting the hard disk to a desktop computer via USB port. Once again I mounted the hard disk back into the Laptop.

While trying to install Windows XP operating system through CD-ROM drive I encountered the following message:

> NTLDR is missing. Press Ctrl+Alt+Del to restart.

I once again tried to install the Operating system but the same message kept appearing. However I am able to access the BIOS on my laptop.

I need a solution to fix. Can anyone guide me to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

While formarting only the data gets deleted on that partition, the MBR still exist on the HDD. When you plug it in and try to start your computer now, it first dedects the drive and then finds the old MBR on it. Since the data is deleted, it can not boot into it. You will have to disable HDD booting (reenable it later!) or move it under the CD-Rom in the bios boot priority list, format the disk completly OR force to boot from the CD via the boot menu.

Answer (score 0):

Change the boot order and set CD-ROM drive at the top of boot menu and then install windows